# How to achieve re-useable components with React and mouse event propagation?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, race-condition, event-propagation

Consider the following typical React document structure:

*Component.jsx*

```
<OuterClickableArea>
    <InnerClickableArea>
        content
    </InnerClickableArea>
</OuterClickableArea>
```

Where these components are composed as follows:

*OuterClickableArea.js*

```
export default class OuterClickableArea extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)

        this.state = {
            clicking: false
        }

        this.onMouseDown = this.onMouseDown.bind(this)
        this.onMouseUp = this.onMouseUp.bind(this)
    }

    onMouseDown() {
        if (!this.state.clicking) {
            this.setState({ clicking: true })
        }
    }

    onMouseUp() {
        if (this.state.clicking) {
            this.setState({ clicking: false })
            this.props.onClick && this.props.onClick.apply(this, arguments)
            console.log('outer area click')
        }
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div
                onMouseDown={this.onMouseDown}
                onMouseUp={this.onMouseUp}
            >
                { this.props.children }
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

With, for the sake of this argument, InnerClickableArea.js having pretty much the same code except for the class name and the console log statement.

Now if you were to run this app and a user would click on the inner clickable area, the following would happen (as expected):

1. outer area registers mouse event handlers
2. inner area registers mouse event handlers
3. user presses mouse down in the inner area
4. inner area's mouseDown listener triggers
5. outer area's mouseDown listener triggers
6. user releases mouse up
7. inner area's mouseUp listener triggers
8. console logs "inner area click"
9. outer area's mouseUp listener triggers
10. console logs "outer area click"

This displays typical event bubbling/propagation -- no surprises so far.

It will output:

```
inner area click
outer area click
```

Now, what if we are creating an app where only a single interaction can happen at a time? For example, imagine an editor where elements could be selected with mouse clicks. When pressed inside the inner area, we would only want to select the inner element.

The simple and obvious solution would be to add a stopPropagation inside the InnerArea component:

*InnerClickableArea.js*

```
    onMouseDown(e) {
        if (!this.state.clicking) {
            e.stopPropagation()
            this.setState({ clicking: true })
        }
    }
```

This works as expected. It will output:

```
inner area click
```

**The problem?**

`InnerClickableArea` hereby implicitly chose for `OuterClickableArea` (and all other parents) not to be able to receive an event. Even though `InnerClickableArea` is not supposed to know about the existence of `OuterClickableArea`. Just like `OuterClickableArea` does not know about `InnerClickableArea` (following separation of concerns and reusability concepts). We created an implicit dependency between the two components where `OuterClickableArea` "knows" that it won't mistakenly have its listeners fired because it "remembers" that InnerClickableArea would stop any event propagation. This seems wrong.

I'm trying not to use stopPropagation to make the app more scalable, because it would be easier to add new features that rely on events without having to remember which components use `stopPropagation` at which time.

Instead, I would like to make the above logic more declarative, e.g. by defining declaratively inside `Component.jsx` whether each of the areas is currently clickable or not. I would make it app state aware, passing down whether the areas are clickable or not, and rename it to `Container.jsx`. Something like this:

*Container.jsx*

```
<OuterClickableArea
    clickable={!this.state.interactionBusy}
    onClicking={this.props.setInteractionBusy.bind(this, true)} />

    <InnerClickableArea
        clickable={!this.state.interactionBusy}
        onClicking={this.props.setInteractionBusy.bind(this, true)} />

            content

    </InnerClickableArea>

</OuterClickableArea>
```

Where `this.props.setInteractionBusy` is a redux action that would cause the app state to be updated. Also, this container would have the app state mapped to its props (not shown above), so `this.state.ineractionBusy` will be defined.

*OuterClickableArea.js* (almost same for InnerClickableArea.js)

```
export default class OuterClickableArea extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)

        this.state = {
            clicking: false
        }

        this.onMouseDown = this.onMouseDown.bind(this)
        this.onMouseUp = this.onMouseUp.bind(this)
    }

    onMouseDown() {
        if (this.props.clickable && !this.state.clicking) {
            this.setState({ clicking: true })
            this.props.onClicking && this.props.onClicking.apply(this, arguments)
        }
    }

    onMouseUp() {
        if (this.state.clicking) {
            this.setState({ clicking: false })
            this.props.onClick && this.props.onClick.apply(this, arguments)
            console.log('outer area click')
        }
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div
                onMouseDown={this.onMouseDown}
                onMouseUp={this.onMouseUp}
            >
                { this.props.children }
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

The problem is that the Javascript event loop seems to run these operations in the following order:

1. both `OuterClickableArea` and `InnerClickableArea` are created with prop `clickable` equal to `true` (because app state interactionBusy defaults to false)
2. outer area registers mouse event handlers
3. inner area registers mouse event handlers
4. user presses mouse down in the inner area
5. inner area's mouseDown listener triggers
6. inner area's onClicking is fired
7. container runs 'setInteractionBusy' action
8. redux app state `interactionBusy` is set to `true`
9. outer area's mouseDown listener triggers (it's `clickable` prop is still `true` because even though the app state `interactionBusy` is `true`, react did not yet cause a re-render; the render operation is put at the end of the Javascript event loop)
10. user releases mouse up
11. inner area's mouseUp listener triggers
12. console logs "inner area click"
13. outer area's mouseUp listener triggers
14. console logs "outer area click"
15. react re-renders `Component.jsx` and passes in `clickable` as `false` to both components, but by now this is too late

This will output:

```
inner area click
outer area click
```

Whereas the desired output is:

```
inner area click
```

App state, therefore, does not help in trying to make these components more independent and reusable. The reason seems to be that even though the state is updated, the container only re-renders at the end of the event loop, and the mouse event propagation triggers are already queued in the event loop.

**My question, therefore, is**: is there an alternative to using app state to be able to work with mouse event propagation in a declarative manner, or is there a better way to implement/execute my above setup with app (redux) state?

Comment: Event gets captured and then bubbled up. Solution is probably to stopPropagation at some point. You can probably add it in the event bind call of site appended after `;` like `onClicking={this.props.setInteractionBusy.bind(this, true); $event.stopPropagation();}`

Comment: @Rikin I don't mind that it's bubbling up, but while bubbling, I would like for other components to be able to review app state and determine independently whether they want to act or not, without implicitly depending on other components.

Comment: Will consider your suggestion to move the `stopPropagation` call one level higher though. In essence that achieves what I want, though it is a little hard to follow (less descriptive than setting whether something is clickable or not).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easiest alternative to this is to add a flag before firing stopPropogation and the flag in this case is an argument.

```
const onMouseDown = (stopPropagation) => {
stopPropagation && event.stopPropagation();
}
```

Now even the application state or prop can even decide to trigger the stoppropagation

```
<div onMouseDown={this.onMouseDown(this.state.stopPropagation)} onMouseUp={this.onMouseUp(this.props.stopPropagation)} >
    <InnerComponent stopPropagation = {true}>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

As @Rikin mentioned and as you alluded to in your answer, event.stopPropagation would solve the your issue in its current form.

`I'm trying not to use stopPropagation to make the app more scalable, because it would be easier to add new features that rely on events without having to remember which components use stopPropagation at which time.`

Is this not a premature concern in terms of the current scope of your component architecture? If you wish for `innerComponent` to be nested within `outerClickableArea` the only way to achieve that is to stopPropagation or to somehow determine which events to ignore. Personally, I would stop propagation for all events, and for those click events for which you selectively want to share state between components, capture the events and dispatch an action (if using redux) to the global state. That way you don't have to worry about selectively ignoring/capturing bubbled events and can update a global source of truth for those events that imply shared state

Comment: I understand your point and had expected it to be brought up. Reality is that I know that this app will become large and that many different components will rely on mouse events. I would call it an optimization but I wouldn't call it premature considering that its need will be inevitable.

Should it not be possible for react to re-render before an event has entirely bubbled up? If it can update state before event propagation has finished, surely it could re-render too? This would allow me to use app state to determine if a component is clickable or not, solving this problem.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of handling the click event and `clickable` state in the component, use a `LOCK` state to Redux state and when user click, the components just emit a `CLICK` action, hold the lock and do the logic. Like this:

1. Both OuterClickableArea and InnerClickableArea are created
2. Redux state with the field `CLICK_LOCK` default to `false`.
3. Outer area registers mouse event handlers
4. Inner area registers mouse event handlers
5. User click in inner area
6. Inner area's `mouseDown` listener triggers
7. Inner area emits action `INNER_MOUSEDOWN`
8. Outer area's `mouseDown` listener triggers
9. Outer area emits action `OUTER_MOUSEDOWN`
10. `INNER_MOUSEDOWN` action set the `CLICK_LOCK` state to `true` and do logic (log `inner area click`).
11. Because `CLICK_LOCK` is `true`, `OUTER_MOUSEDOWN` do nothing.
12. Inner area's `mouseUp` listener triggers
13. Inner area emits action `INNER_MOUSEUP`
14. Outer area's `mouseUp` listener triggers
15. Outer area emits action `OUTER_MOUSEUP`
16. `INNER_MOUSEUP` action set the `CLICK_LOCK` state to `false`.
17. `OUTER_MOUSEUP` action set the `CLICK_LOCK` state to `false`.
18. Nothing have to be re-render unless the click logic change some state.

**Note:**

- This approach work by having a lock in a region, at one time, only one component can `click`. Each component do not have to know about the others, but need a global state (Redux) to orchestrate.
- If the rate of clicking is high, this approach performance might not be good.
- Currently Redux actions is [guaranteed to be emitted synchronously](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux/issues/1199). Not sure about the future.

Comment: Do you mean that you want to connect the innerClickableArea directly to redux? I would prefer to only connect the outer area and pass in props to innerClickableArea. That's the same as what I have done before and doesn't work due to a race condition.

Answer (score 1):

I'm suspecting that you are about to create something like overlay modal, where there will be component that should be closed when the outer component or the container component was clicked, if that's the case, you could use [react-overlays](https://github.com/react-bootstrap/react-overlays) instead of recreating the whole thing, you could also learn on how they handle this kind of implementation if you have different purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Have you though of passing the information if the event was already processed in the event itself?

```
const handleClick = e => {
    if (!e.nativeEvent.wasProcessed) {
      // do something
      e.nativeEvent.wasProcessed = true;
    }
  };
```

This way the outer component can check that the event was already processed by one of it's childrens while the event will still bubble up.

I've put up a sample that nests two Clickable components. The mousedown event gets processed only by the innermost Clickable component user clicked on: https://codesandbox.io/s/2wmxxzormy

Disclaimer: I could not find any information on this exactly being a bad practice, but in general modifying an object you do not own can lead to e.g. naming collisions in the future.

Comment: The problem with this approach is that `.wasProcessed` is implicitly depended upon. The implementation assumes that another component sets this but this is not defined anywhere.

Comment: Ah ok, i probably understand your question better now. Would sending the blocking flag name as a component's prop work for you? Check out adjusted sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/j32lqwwp75
I've seen you accepted the stopPropagation answer which is a viable solution, but please note there are possible side effects: https://css-tricks.com/dangers-stopping-event-propagation/